# Renaming Multiple Layers of Raster Stack in Plots

Tags: r, plot, stack, raster, rastervis

I am trying to rename multiple layers (January, February, March to Jan, Feb, Mar...Dec) in the plot using rasterVis. I followed the code as mentioned below. Using the code the layers can be renamed as 1,2,3, but i am unable to rename the layers as Jan, Feb, and March.

```
levelplot(data,par.settings=BuRdTheme(),names.attr=c(as.character(1:3)))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Does `levelplot(data, names.attr=c("Jan","Feb","March"))` not work?

Comment: If you want the abbreviated month names, they are in `month.abb`. So if you have a 12 layer stack, then `levelplot(s12, names.attr=month.abb)` should do it.